# Why is list comprehension slower than a for loop?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension, benchmarking

Why is the for loop appending faster than list comprehension
For Loop Time: 7.214778099999876
List Comprehension Time: 7.4003780000002735

Code 1:

```
import timeit

mycode = '''
new_list=[]
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
for obj in x:
    if obj %2==0:
        new_list.append(obj)
'''
 
print (timeit.timeit(stmt = mycode,
                     number = 10000000))
```

Code 2:

```
import timeit

mycode = '''
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
new_list=[obj for obj in x if obj %2==0]
'''

print (timeit.timeit(stmt = mycode,
                     number = 10000000))
```

I expected the for loop to be slower than list comprehension when it came to appending repeatedly but that was not the case.

Comment: I think this is Python.  That would be the most important tag...

Comment: I would not generalized like that, ie _a list comprehension is slower than a for-loop_, it depends _also_ on the size of the data. I tested with `x=[1,2,3,4,5]*50` and `number=1_000_000` and the comprehension was faster

Answer (score 1):

This is because the **list comprehension version has a bigger startup overhead**. The bigger the list the faster the list comprehension is compared to the basic loop.
Indeed, with `x=list(range(15))` the list comprehension is 10% faster on my machine as opposed to 10% slower for the provided input. With `x=list(range(1000))`, the list comprehension is 25% faster than the other version.

Answer (score 1):

If you disassemble these python functions, you will see, that list comprehension compiles to a separate code object with it's own costs.

And if you trace for memory allocations, they are the same.

You can check allocations with the following code

```
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()

def a():
    new_list = []
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for obj in x:
        if obj % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(obj)


def b():
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    new_list = [obj for obj in x if obj % 2 == 0]

a()
b()

snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')

print("[ Top 10 ]")
for stat in top_stats[:10]:
    print(stat)
```

Results in

```
[ Top 10 ]
xxx:20: size=144 B, count=1, average=144 B
xxx:12: size=144 B, count=1, average=144 B
```

And bytecode with

```
import dis
print(dis.dis(a))
print('----------------')
print(dis.dis(b))
```

You will see something like

```
Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x1012d1790, file "xxx", line 18>:
 18           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                10 (to 26)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (obj)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (obj)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
             12 BINARY_MODULO
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             16 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        2 (to 4)
             20 LOAD_FAST                1 (obj)
             22 LIST_APPEND              2
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2 (to 4)
        >>   26 RETURN_VALUE
```

In case of b, but not in case of a, which has a lot of extra commands.